# Parsing HTML in React, issues with href

Tags: html, reactjs, parsing

I'm having some issues parsing html I get from API. I have tried dangerouslySetInnerHTML, react-html-parser and html-react-parser.
All three work but all three give me a line break before and after <a href.

[example of the href parsing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXUhL.png)

The html from API looks fine to me allthough I'm not very experienced:

```
Bitcoin uses the <a href=\"https://www.coingecko.com/en?hashing_algorithm=SHA-256\">SHA-256</a> hashing algorithm with an average transaction confirmation time of 10 minutes.
```

Anyone encountered similar issues?
Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, please provide the input html as text format and your code, so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unless the output HTML contains `<br>` or `<p>` tags wrapped around those links, this is almost certainly going to be a CSS issue (have you maybe set `display:block` on your links?)

Comment: Hello. Sorry but I'm not sure if I understand? I have pasted in a fragment of the string I'm getting from API. This fragment contains an anchor tag. All 3 methods I tried parse the a href to display as a link, but they also add a line break before and after the link. so that the link is the only text in that line. Like shown on the screenshot. Does this make sense? Thanks

Comment: Daniel Beck: you're a genius Sir. Had display: flex on this element. removed it and that fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's fine to answer my own question: thanks to Daniel Beck's hint I was able to figure it out.
The parser turns the text into an array of objects, where regular text is a string and anchor tags are objects. My container had display: flex and flex-direction: column and that's why links appeared in a separate line.
Thanks